# How I do to set a file in a showSaveDialog through a JFileChooser

Tags: java, jfilechooser

Well, I make a PDF file with iText, and it's always well created. But now I want to set the generated PDF file to a dialog, to give the user the way to save it where he/she wants.

I think I have to use showSaveDialog to do the task I want, but I tried some solutions without any result I want, because I just get to show the dialog with home folder as selected file.

iText works correctly, I only need a code to save the generated PDF file where the user wants, and destroy the PDF file from the project folder after the user saved it through the dialog.

This is the code I'm using now.

```
JFileChooser elegidor = new JFileChooser();
File f2 = new File("filePDF.pdf");

elegidor.setFileSelectionMode(JFileChooser.DIRECTORIES_ONLY);

elegidor.showSaveDialog(null);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I found a solution for my problem. I choose to move the PDF file, managing it as a common file, and it works.

```
JFileChooser elegidor = new JFileChooser();
        File originalFile = new File(System.getProperty("user.dir"), "filePDF.pdf");

        elegidor.setCurrentDirectory(new File(System.getProperty("user.dir")));

        elegidor.setSelectedFile(originalFile);

        elegidor.setFileSelectionMode(JFileChooser.FILES_ONLY);

        int returnVal = elegidor.showSaveDialog(null);
        File destinationFile = null;
        if (returnVal == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) {
            destinationFile = new File(elegidor.getSelectedFile().getAbsolutePath());

            if (!destinationFile.getAbsolutePath().equals(originalFile.getAbsolutePath())) {
                InputStream in = new FileInputStream(originalFile);

                OutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(destinationFile);

                byte[] buf = new byte[1024];
                int len;
                while ((len = in.read(buf)) > 0) {
                    out.write(buf, 0, len);
                }
                in.close();
                out.close();
            }
        }

        if (!destinationFile.getAbsolutePath().equals(originalFile.getAbsolutePath())) {
            originalFile.delete();
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

All JFileChooser does is show a Dialog through which a `File` can be selected. There is no functionality to automatically save / load anything to the file/directory... You have to implement that yourself, though the [Apache Commons](http://commons.apache.org/) library and [FileUtils](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-io/apidocs/org/apache/commons/io/FileUtils.html) might be useful to you

Comment: I wouldn't be asking here if the code does the thing I want. I don't know how to set the created PDF file to the dialog.